# LaTex: How to exactly display List of Tables (figures)

Tags: latex

I am using *\documentclass{book}*. In my 'appendix' chapter, I have tables with caption name like this
[image]

However, when I use *\listoftables*, the automatically generated table list is one like this

[image]

How can I make the list of tables look exactly like the name showed in appendix? Thank you!

Comment: Since the ToC can be handled by many packages, as well as the float caption formatting, please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your current setup. It would go a long way in providing experts with the requirements of your usage.

Comment: Thank you @Werner My problem is solved, by using a tocloft package.